# mixed MTB/road bike for touring: uncleanliness of a Frankenstein setup

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur, touring, compatibility

*It appears that there are similar threads, so I'll reformulate it with more specific questions and taking the cue from comments.*

I am assembling my brand-new touring bike on a LHT frame, and I'd like to make STI shifters work on it. My setup at the moment is

- shifters shimano 105 STI
- crankset shimano LX 48-36-26
- cassette+chain 10 speeds shimano XT

[Apparently](http://www.bikeforums.net/bicycle-mechanics/673861-how-use-10-spd-sti-shifters-10-spd-11-36-cassette-success-story.html) to make STI work with rear MTB derailleurs, one needs to take the 9 speed RD, since new 10 speeds have different pull ratio. What concerns me most, at the moment, is the dirtiness that comes from the choice:

- using a 10s chain on a 9s rear derailleur, due to different thickness
- using a road FD (e.g. shimano 105 triple) with a MTB RD and with a 48-36-26 crank
- other issues that you will suggest

do you think it would affect shifting smoothness and durability of the setup to use this kind of melting-pot solution?

**bonus question**: on this compatibility reference, are you aware of any difference between shimano SHADOW XT RD and normal XT RD?

**bonus solution**: I am not a STI religious, so if issues are real I might shift to barends to make a fast and long lasting fix. Anyway, I'd like to stay on brifters if problems are not that significant.

thanks a lot!

Comment: The difference between brifters and bar-end shifters is pretty significant, I wouldn't make the change just because of a minor hassle getting the right components. Better to buy an RD that works IMO

Comment: sure, I actually have no experience with any of the two (always toured with a MTB) so that would be a major change in any case. Let's say there is also barends-vs-sti pros and cons hidden question :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shimano Compatibility](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21421/shimano-compatibility) and many others.

Comment: Sorry, have you not worked out that the speed parts are designed for is pretty important, even from the same manufacturer? It's just that you've managed to work out that you need 9-speed components, yet you're still proposing to buy a 10-speed front derailleur. I'd be tempted to take the bike to a shop and ask them to help.

Comment: sorry peteH, but I don't understand your comment (and its tone). Everything in the setup is 10 speed, I am using 9 speed RD just because the pull ratio seems to be correct in that case, i.e. in practice I am still using 10 speeds. I don't see how taking a 9 speed FD would help. Also, if I were into taking the bike to a shop I wouldn't write on this website, would I? I thought that the policy of the website were to _exchange_ advices, not to send people to the closest bike shop for them.

Comment: I'm just saying that the manufacturer is important, and so is the number of speeds on the cassette. If you're buying stuff in any case, it's best to stay consistent.

Comment: The policy of this site is, to quote PeteH's profile, "to be on here to argue". *Mountain* 9-speed derailleurs have the same pull ratio as all road derailleurs since 90s, and different pull ratio from 10-speed mountain derailleurs. 10-speed chain is narrower, and that may cause problems when mixing 10-speed chain and 9-speed derailleur.

Comment: 10 speed and 9 speed (And all others) have the same internal width (3/32"). Its the outside measurement that narrows with 10,11 and 12 speed chains.

Comment: thank you mattnz, so no practical issues on the chain-RD side

Comment: According to multiple sources, internal speed for 9-speed chain is around 6.8 mm and 10-speed chain 5.9 to 6.2 mm.

Comment: @ojs can you find these sources? it actually makes a huge difference if I am raping my chain or not...

Comment: @LorenzoP sorry, I read the tables wrong. Apparently internal width is the same. What I don't understand is why cog thickness changes even if internal chain width stays the same.

Comment: I'd just buy a 9 speed Shimano mountain derailleur. Brifters are less robust than bar ends physically; if you're on a long tour, its practically impossible to destroy bar ends or downtube shifters. A decent crash can wreck a brifter.

Comment: ojs can you link these tabs? I'd like to use them for future references! @batman do you think that shadow/no shadow makes a difference?

Comment: Two questions: (1) Does LHT stand for Surly Long Haul Trucker, or something else? (2) Why do you want to use a mountain RD? IMO there is no difference in quality or durability for touring use. I'm not sure of your motivation. I understand wanting STI, but not the mountain part. Why "downgrade" to 9 speed, when you call have everything you want with 10 speed road components?

Comment: My guess as to why he wants a mountain derailleur... more gear range. Most 10-speed road shifters claim to max out at 28 or 30 tooth max cog size. MTB can go to 36t max in rear and deal better with a triple front.

Comment: These days, GRX adds an additional set of options, though as they're designed for 1× or 2× systems, combining them with a triple probably means exceeding the spec for total range (and only the 1× versions can handle massive cogs on the back)

Answer (score 2):

10 speed brifters with a shadow Deore XT rear derailleur will work fine. Tested.

Your front derailleur will work great with mountain bike crankset - in fact, some new touring bikes use this exact setup!

All 9 speed, high end derailleurs like Deore XT is "Shadow", but not "Shadow Plus". (Shadow plus have clutch, but no 9 speed derailleur has clutch). Shadow is a fancy word for a heavier spring and more streamlined derailleur, that does not expose itself too much, hence lesser risk of breaking it due to hitting something, like a rock.

In your setup, there is no risk of incompatibility, UNLESS your frame is a road bike frame, which the front derailleur you have is designed for - MTB and road seatposts have different angles, so with an MTB frame, road derailleur compatibility can be a bit sketchy.